# Accessing About us information on closed facebook group

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know how to get any opened group information using:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=GROUP_ID
```

but with closed group, it shows that

```
Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

However, I can see `About` information on a closed group without joining the group. For example: 
https://www.facebook.com/groups/503894262988490

I can see *This is where we share recipes, pictures of food and near-food, and info about restaurants and other foodie topics.*

So how can I retrieve this 'about' information with jQuery?

Comment: You can't. It is not available in the API

Comment: But I can see that piece of information as a facebook user. Is there any possible ways to access it?

Comment: Just because you can see it as a Facebook use doesn't mean you can see it using the API